# DC removal from IQ samples

Tags: digital-communications

I am wondering what is the proper way to remove DC component from PSK modulated signals. Should I calculate mean value for I and Q channel separately and correct then samples in each of the channel or calculate one mean value for I and Q channel as one channel with interleaved samples (IQIQIQIQ) and then correct samples. What do you think?

Comment: i think you should run $i[n]$ and $q[n]$ through identical high-pass filters to remove DC.  if they are fixed-point signals there might be some [additional worry for you](https://dspguru.com/dsp/tricks/fixed-point-dc-blocking-filter-with-noise-shaping/).

Comment: And see this post from @RichardLyons on linear-phase DC removal filters: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/58.php  (removing I and Q each with their own filters as RBJ suggested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"What do you think" is the wrong question here: It's not a matter of opinion. Your second approach is mathematically simply not calculating the mean of a series of *complex* numbers. The mean of a complex sequence is w.l.o.g. complex, the mean of your IQIQIQIQ is real, so it can't possibly be the mean/DC component.

Comment: What does w.l.o.g means?

Comment: without loss of generality (i.e. there might be a complex signal that has a mean with a zero imaginary part, but in the general case, the mean of complex signals is a complex number with both a real and an imaginary part)